# Flysystem local asset from outside public folder in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, assets, flysystem

I have the following method that will get an asset depending on which CDN is used:

```
 public function getAsset($filename, $dir = null, $prefix = null)
    {
        $extension = File::extension($filename);
        $name = File::name($filename);

        $filename = $dir . $prefix . $name . '.' . $extension;

        if(Flysystem::getDefaultConnection() == 'awss3') return Flysystem::getAdapter()->getClient()->getObjectUrl('xxxx', $filename);
        if(Flysystem::getDefaultConnection() == 'local') return Flysystem::getAdapter()->getClient()->getObjectUrl($filename);
    }
```

When 'local' storage is selected (in a config) I want to be able to get the asset from the app/storage/temp/media/ directory and display them to the as an image in a  tag, how can I modify the above to work like that?

How do I even get an asset from outside the public directory anyway?